# IDependencyResolver null exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection

I'm trying to inject some dependencies in my Controller using the IDependencyResolver. This is my controller.

```
public class MyController: ApiController
{
    private IMyService m_myService;

    public MyController()
    {

    }

    public MyController(IMyService myService)
    {
        m_myService = myService;
    }
   //Other code....
}
```

I'm using a custom serviceProvider which has all my app dependencies inside, and which was provided to me and is mandatory use it. Here is the implementation of the IDependencyResolver with my serviceProvider that I'm using.

```
public class ServiceProviderResolver: IDependencyResolver
{
    private ServiceProvider m_serviceProvider;


    public ServiceProviderResolver(ServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        m_serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        m_serviceProvider = null;
    }

    public IDependencyScope BeginScope()
    {
        return new ServiceProviderResolver(m_serviceProvider);
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        object result = null;
        try
        {
            MethodInfo serviceProviderGetMethod =
                m_serviceProvider.GetType().GetMethod("Get").MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] {serviceType});
            result = serviceProviderGetMethod.Invoke(m_serviceProvider, null);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
        return result;
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        //Code is the same because our container only have an object for each Type
        object result = null;
        try
        {
            MethodInfo serviceProviderGetMethod =
                m_serviceProvider.GetType().GetMethod("Get").MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { serviceType });
            result = serviceProviderGetMethod.Invoke(m_serviceProvider, null);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
        return (IEnumerable<object>) result;
    }
}
```

The problem arises when I start my webApi I get a Null Exception and it crashes.

```
Startup.cs

public class Startup
{
    //This property is being instantiated before calling configuration function
    public static ServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; set; }

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder application)
    {
        application.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        HttpConfiguration configuration = new HttpConfiguration();
        configuration.DependencyResolver = new ServiceProviderResolver(ServiceProvider);

        // Attribute routing.
        configuration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        application.UseWebApi(configuration);

        configuration.EnsureInitialized();
    }
}
```

EDIT:
When I call UseWebApi method inside the Startup class. The code is calling GetService method of my dependencyResolver and the Type passed by parameter is IHostBufferPolicySelector.

Any help will be so appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Where are you assigning ServiceProvider? Also post your exception details (stack trace included).

Comment: Hi @FedericoDipuma I just solved it like 3 mins ago. Thank you for your interest!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved it. The problem was with the GetServices(Type serviceType). I was returning in some cases null and the proper way to do this is if you have null return a new list. The following code solved it

```
public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
{
    //Code is the same because our container only have an object for each Type
    object result = null;
    try
    {
        MethodInfo serviceProviderGetMethod =
            m_serviceProvider.GetType().GetMethod("Get").MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { serviceType });
        result = serviceProviderGetMethod.Invoke(m_serviceProvider, null);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }

    if(resul == null)
    {
       return new List<object>();
    }
    return (IEnumerable<object>) result;
}
```